# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tBodies' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an error when running my ExtJS webApp. The error does not appear on any other machine that I pull the code to.

The error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tBodies' of null

 renderChildren: function() {
    var me = this,
        items = me.getLayoutItems(),
        tbody = me.owner.getTargetEl().child('table', true).tBodies[0],
        rows = tbody.rows,
        i = 0,
        len = items.length,
        hiddenItems = me.getHiddenItems(),
        cells, curCell, rowIdx, cellIdx, item, trEl, tdEl, itemCt, el;

    cells = me.calculateCells(items);
```

It fails at :

```
tbody = me.owner.getTargetEl().child('table', true).tBodies[0],
```

Can anyone try and shed some light on how I can resolve this? I've tried in Firefox and it works, just Chrome throws an error. I've cleared my cache, local storage etc.

Comment: So it is not finding a table... debug to see what is different with `getTargetEl()`

Comment: Why would this be an issue in Chrome on my PC and not Firefox or Chrome on any other machine?

Comment: Debug and find out....Could be extensions and many other factors.

Comment: I had a look, it is to do with the layout of my panel. Changing from table to hbox works. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Benirving92, are you using table layout in your view, and you are trying to update some field like combobox or grid inside it. You can solve the issue by simply removing the table layout and replacing it with vbox and multiple hbox layout. .... Hope this helps